# Swift 3 Array Declaration Benefits

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, declare

When I learned Swift I always declared my arrays like so

```
var myArrayDeclaration: [String]
```

However in many tutorials and even in books released by Apple arrays are declared like so

```
var appleArrayDeclaration = [String]()
```

On the surface both appear to work exactly the same when I use them. Is there a reason why tutorials and Apple almost exclusively show the second method? Or is it developers preference?

Comment: The first one is just declaring a property that holds a `[String]` and assigning nothing to it.  The second one is actually creating an array and assigning it to the property.

Comment: `var myArrayDeclaration: [String] = []` would be the equivalent of the second snippet.  Both are equivalent to `Array<String>()`.

Comment: Both are not same, the first is declaring that the `myArrayDeclaration` which is never initialised, which will be in the future down the lines of code. Second is declaring and initialising the `appleArrayDeclaration` to the empty array. It depends on your use case.

Answer (score -3):

The Second method use type inference, and its usually preferred by Apple and Developers since express the simplicity and expressiveness of swift 3 language optimization.

Btw, both methods work and do the job!

Comment: "both methods work and do the job" is just wrong. They are doing very different jobs.